# How to include AWS RDS's Certificate bundle (PEM) into Flaskext.mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, amazon-rds

I am trying to establish an SSL connection from my Flask application to Amazon Web Service Relational Database Service MYSQL.
I am using Flask-MySQL extension that allows me to connect to the database.

Here is my code in my database connection 'db.py':

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flaskapp.__init__ import *


mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = os.getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE_USER")
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = os.getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD")
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = os.getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE_DB")
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = os.getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST")
app.config['MYSQL_SSL_CA'] = 
'mysql+pymysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@<AWS RDS ENDPOINT>/<SCHEMA>?sslmode=verify-ca&sslrootcert=ap-southeast-1-bundle.pem'
mysql.init_app(app)
```

When I tried to make a query, there is an error displaying:

```
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\nintu\Desktop\FYP-21-S4-09\backend\flaskapp\routes.py", line 25, in zxc
    conn = mysql.connect()
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 65, in connect
    return pymysql.connect(**self.connect_args)
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 285, in __init__
    self.ctx = self._create_ssl_ctx(ssl)
  File "C:\Users\nintu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 365, in _create_ssl_ctx
    ca = sslp.get("ca")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Anyone has any idea where did I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys I solved the issue by changing from MySQL extension to flask sqlalchemy

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@AWS-END-POINT/DataBaseSchema?ssl_ca=/your-aws-bundle.pem'